# R, arguments imply differing number of row

Tags: r, dataframe

I generated a data frame (df) in R (see below). If I use the column "x2" instead of "x2a" to make the data frame everything works well. However, as soon as I use "x2a" instead of "x2" I get an error because the input of "x2a" is of various lengths. Do you have an idea how I can change the code that it is going to work with column "x2a"?

Error message with "x2a":

```
Error in data.frame(Id = rep(df$Id), Noise = unlist(split_it), Start = rep(df$Start),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 16
```

Code to reproduce the data frame and error

```
x1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
x2 <- c("[1,3,5,6,7]","[5,7,8,9,10]","[3,4,5,8,9]")
x2a <- c("[1,3,5]","[5,7,8,9,10, 20, 30, 24]","[3,4,5,8,9]")
x3 <- c(8000, 74555, 623334)
x4 <- c(9000, 76000, 623500)

df <- data.frame(cbind(x1, x2a, x3, x4))
colnames(df) <- c("Id", "Noise", "Start", "End")
df$Start <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Start))
df$End <- as.numeric(as.character(df$End))

# remove square brackets
df$Noise <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", df$Noise)

# split 
split_it <- strsplit(df$Noise, split = ",")
df_2 <- data.frame(Id = rep(df$Id), Noise = unlist(split_it), Start = rep(df$Start), End = rep(df$End))
df_2 <- df_2[order(df_2$Id),]
rownames(df_2) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

What I'm inferring you *want* is not something R can "intuit" for you: you want it to repeat the values in `Id` based on the number of elements found when `strsplit` did its work. (How should R know to look in one object and arbitrarily repeat another?)

Try using `rep(., times=.)` to specify how many times each element of `Id` (etc) should be repeated in order to stay "in step" with `Noise`.

```r
# split 
split_it <- strsplit(df$Noise, split = ",")
n <- lengths(split_it)
print(n)
# [1] 3 8 5

df_2 <- data.frame(Id = rep(df$Id, times=n),
                   Noise = unlist(split_it),
                   Start = rep(df$Start, times=n),
                   End = rep(df$End, times=n))
df_2 <- df_2[order(df_2$Id),]
rownames(df_2) <- NULL
df_2
#    Id Noise  Start    End
# 1   A     1   8000   9000
# 2   A     3   8000   9000
# 3   A     5   8000   9000
# 4   B     5  74555  76000
# 5   B     7  74555  76000
# 6   B     8  74555  76000
# 7   B     9  74555  76000
# 8   B    10  74555  76000
# 9   B    20  74555  76000
# 10  B    30  74555  76000
# 11  B    24  74555  76000
# 12  C     3 623334 623500
# 13  C     4 623334 623500
# 14  C     5 623334 623500
# 15  C     8 623334 623500
# 16  C     9 623334 623500
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Noise = strsplit(Noise, split = ",")) %>%
  unnest(Noise) %>%
  mutate(Noise = as.integer(Noise))   # I'm inferring this is desired, not required
# # A tibble: 16 x 4
#    Id    Noise  Start    End
#    <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1 A         1   8000   9000
#  2 A         3   8000   9000
#  3 A         5   8000   9000
#  4 B         5  74555  76000
#  5 B         7  74555  76000
#  6 B         8  74555  76000
#  7 B         9  74555  76000
#  8 B        10  74555  76000
#  9 B        20  74555  76000
# 10 B        30  74555  76000
# 11 B        24  74555  76000
# 12 C         3 623334 623500
# 13 C         4 623334 623500
# 14 C         5 623334 623500
# 15 C         8 623334 623500
# 16 C         9 623334 623500
```